# Ajax jQuery not working for Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have designed a filter page, which uses jquery to dynamically show the user a set of products in a specific order , like ascending / descending ,

```
$.ajax({
    type:'Get',
    url:'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showAllOptions',
    data : "prod="+prod,
    cache: false,
    success:function(response) {
        $.each(response, function( index, value ) { 
            alert(index);
        }); 
    }   
});
```

This code works fine with FireFox, and I get my ajax response in the required sequence,
but not the same with Google Chrome, where the result is shown in one specific order regardless of input.

NOTE:

The ajax response is a LinkedHashMap, so it should maintain the order of the objects sent by the controller. 
Can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Comment: change data to data:{prod:prod}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    type:'Get',
    url:'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showAllOptions',
    data : {prod:prod},
    cache: false,
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(response) {
        $.each(response, function( index, value ) { 
            alert(index);
        }); 
    }   
});
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: You nedd set data type json for respons convert json and set daata for object

Comment: @Harutyun : got it , but that didn't work for me. Still not able to figure out why the issue is with chrome and not with firefox